# Recursively call function's return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Is there builtin that allows shortening this code snippet:

```
for i in range(5):
    obj = obj.getobj()
    if obj is None:
        break
print(i)
```

I thought of using `itertools.accumulate` together with `filter` and `lambda` but it turns it unreadable and ugly.

I'm using this for tree traversal but it's relevant for many other areas and may come in many forms such as:

```
for i in range(5):
    func = func()
```

P.S. I'm not entirely sure if "recursion" is the appropriate term but it somehow resembled it for me.

Comment: I don't think the snippet needs shortening? It seems clear enough! you can put it in a function named `recurse_calls` and use it!

Comment: It is quite clear, and it's currently a great solution, but I just wonder if there's any builtin that does it. Just like you're able to create everything in `itertools` using `yield` :-)

Comment: @MoxieBall it's just to demonstrate I'm using the variable `i` ofc.

Comment: @MoxieBall `for i in range(5)` defines `i` in that scope, you're welcome to open the interpreter and check :-)

Comment: It looks like you want `reduce`, shooter but not more readable

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I thought of `reduce` but I may cut it in the middle (`if obj is None`) and reduce won't suffice for that, only `accumulate`.

Comment: Trampolining, it's called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pretty easily write a helper function for this:

```
def traverse(func, obj, max=5, sentinel=None):
    last = obj
    for i in range(max):
        obj = func(obj)
        if obj is sentinel:
            break
        last = obj
    return last
```

Rather than hard-coding the `obj = obj.getobj()` call, we pass in a function for this. The maximum number of iterations and sentinel value are also parameterized. Presuming you might want the last non-`None` value, this function also tracks this value and returns it.

Usage:

```
traverse(lambda o: o.getobj(), obj)   

# slightly faster, uses class's method directly
# but all objects in the chain must be same type
traverse(type(obj).getobj, obj)
```

Comment: I appreciate the usefulness of this answer but it does seem to answer the question "how do I make this code shorter" with "by making it longer and putting it somewhere else"

Comment: @MoxieBall I see your point, but it's common practice to identify a pattern and write code to handle it generically. If the pattern is used more than a couple of times, the aggregate amount of code is shorter. Also, once you grok the function, each use of the pattern is clearer.

Comment: Btw, `operator.methodcaller("getobj")` is what you're looking for instead of the `lambda`.

Comment: Yes, that's another way to do it.